# How to call model function from Yii2 Gridview value

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm trying to display the model data in the GridView column value, but it keep shows error: *Call to a member function getUSD() on string*.
I only want to display one data in that data cell. Can anyone know what's the problem?

Model code:

```
public static function getUSD(){
    $getUSD = Rate::find()
            ->select('rate')
            ->where(['currency_name' => 'USD'])
            ->orderBy('rate_id DESC')
            ->one();
        return $getUSD;
}
```

Code in the GirdView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'summary' => '',
'columns' => [
    [
        'label' => 'USD',
        'value' => function($model){
            return $model->getUSD();
        }
    ],
```

Expected output:

```
|USD|  
| 4.102|
```

Comment: Clarify the desired output. Since you not present in what form data is stored in DB

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I want my output same as the one in my db which stored as float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the object from the function rather than the actual `rate` column value, you should instead be getting the error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

rather the one you are mentioning, because the gridview column expects you to return string and when trying to render the cell using the `yii\grid\DataColumn::renderDataCellContent` which calls the `yii\i18n\Formatter` to render as text which finds the object instead in your case.

Also you have defined the function as getter and yii says

> Nearly every core class in the Yii framework extends from
>   `yii\base\BaseObject` or a child class. This means, that whenever you
>   see a getter or setter in a core class, you can use it like a
>   property.

And change your function to

```
public static function getUSD()
{
    $rate = Rate::find()
        ->select('rate')
        ->where(['currency_name' => 'USD'])
        ->orderBy('rate_id DESC')
        ->one();

    return null !== $rate ? $rate->rate : 'NA';
}
```

And call it like below.

```
echo GridView::widget(
    [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'summary' => '',
        'columns' => [
            [
                'label' => 'USD',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->USD;
                },

            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

If you dont wish to change the `getUSD()` function then you might have to check it inside the gridview like below

```
echo GridView::widget(
    [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'summary' => '',
        'columns' => [
            [
                'label' => 'USD',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return null !== $model->USD ? $model->USD->rate: 'NA';
                },

            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Comment: thanks, could you mind explain to me about the 'rate' in the '$rate->rate'? What is it? I'm abit confuse about it. And also, since every gridview in Yii2 framework require dataprovider , should I change any code in my controller?

Comment: @ahzy96 `$rate->rate` is accessing the `rate` column that you are selecting in your query, and you dont need to change anything in your controller

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Your solution work fine for me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> If you handle same data over and over again the same time, then I would consider calling them not statically and save (in between) results somewhere (in a property of the class for example), saving you from having too many queries.

Like an answer for your question You can call it this way:

```
return $model::getUSD()->rate; //Call to a static method from current model
```

or

```
return 'USD ' . $model::getUSD()->rate; //Call to a static method from current model
```

**Like an option described at the beginning you can do this way too:**

```
$model = new MyModel();
$rate = MyModel::getUSD()->rate;//get value of current rate

//Gridview

<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'summary' => '',
'columns' => [
    [
        'label' => 'USD',
        'value' => function($model) use ($rate){
            return 'USD' . $rate; //Your initially stored rate
        }
    ],
```

Comment: I have use the both 'return' you shown above but it show error 'Class 2020-03-05' not found. The '2020-03-05' is the date in the database but in my query I use is to find only the rate. Why it will show the class not found?

Comment: Provide both models and attributes they use

Comment: Did you mean to put 'attribute' => 'rate' like this under the column section?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getUSD()` function does not return an string, returns an object with the attribute `rate`.

In order for it to work as you do you must return directly the value of the object like:

```
public static function getUSD(){

    $getUSD = Rate::find()
            ->select('rate')
            ->where(['currency_name' => 'USD'])
            ->orderBy('rate_id DESC')
            ->one();

        return $getUSD ? $getUSD->rate : null;
}
```

Now you first check if the query found something, and if it found something then you return the property `rate`.

Then getUSD is an static method so you should not do like `$model->getUsd()` but `$model::getUSD()`.